# React Update certain values after initial rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an inherited React app that i need to fix but after a few days, im stuck and need help.

I have a filtering panel on the left side which contains a 5 categories and items within their categories below it, each item has a checkbox next to it and when you click it, it updates the results on the right side, this works fine.

However i have a task to update the numbers next to the links in the filter panel, based on what was clicked and would like to know if there is a way to create the filters links first and then only update the number next to the link upon click.

All the code resides in the render method, any help would be great.

Comment: Can you post some code please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What are these "numbers next to the links"? Where do they get those from? What do they depend on? Are the "links" same as "items having checkbox next to it"? Posting some code would help

Comment: You're right guys, sorry here's the code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/tekked/hv427vdo/2/